# Локальный кэш веб-приложения

Tags: angularjs

Всем доброго дня! В веб-проекте на Angular 2 появилась необходимость создания большого локального кэша данных на рабочем месте пользователя.  Информация для кэша хранится в базе данных под управлением MS SQL Server. Стоит задача при обращение к контролю убрать обращения к базе данных совсем. Какие есть эффективные способы хранения данных для веб-приложения на клиенте на сегодняшний день? Нужна идея. Может несколько вразрез с направленностью данного сайта, тут больше рассматриваются технические проблемы, извините, но не верю, что никто из участников SO не сталкивался с подобным. Спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам нужно хранить довольно много данных на клиенте на постоянной основе и нужна поддержка большинства современных браузеров, то у вас есть 2 варианта.

**LocalStorage**

Позволяет хранить любые данные в виде строк. [Поддерживается](http://caniuse.com/#search=Web%20Storage) почти всеми современными браузерами. Есть ограничение на максимальный объем хранимых данных на домен: от 5 до 10 мегабайт в зависимости от браузера. [Тут](http://dev-test.nemikor.com/web-storage/support-test/) есть статистика по размеру хранилища и тест.

**IndexedDB**

Имеет более сложное API по сравнению с LocalStorage и немного хуже [поддерживается браузерами](http://caniuse.com/#search=indexdb). Зато максимальный объем хранимой информации зависит от свободного объема на жестком диске пользователя, но не может превышать 10% от свободного объема на диске. [Удобная библиотека](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) для работы с IndexedDB

*Другие варианты хранения данных на клиенте*

1. WebSQL - [не работает](http://caniuse.com/#search=WebSQL) в Internet Explorer, MS Edge и Firefox. В добавок к этому спецификация WebSQL больше не поддерживается и, возможно, хром и сафари уберут поддержу WebSQL в будущих версиях. (Возможно подходит вам, если вы ориентируетесь на хром или сафари)
2. Куки - не позволяют хранить много данных и передаются с каждым запросом в заголовках на сервер (Вам не подходят)
3. SessionStorage - тоже что и LocalStorage, но только данных хранятся до закрытии вкладки. (Вам не подходит)

**Итого:** лучше всего вам подходит WebSQL (если не считать проблем с поддержкой), затем IndexedDB (большой объем хранимых данных) и LocalStorage на крайний случай.

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь, Ваш совет просто бесценен. Думаю, что будем пробовать разные варианты и смотреть, что более подходит. Насчет поддержки браузеров - интересен IE/Edge (в первую очередь), Chrome. Под остальные браузеры пока не ориентируемся.

Comment: @Andrew тогда, вероятно, IndexedDB ваш выбор. Хотя IE/Edge есть некоторые баги в реализации IndexedDB. Ознакомитесь с известными багами перед началом https://gist.github.com/nolanlawson/a841ee23436410f37168